# Django can't create object - RelatedObjectDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model `Payment` and model `Invoice`. The model invoice has an attribute `payment` which is a `OneToOneField` field with `null=True` and `blank=True`.

The problem is that Django doesn't allow me to create a payment.

```
>>> Payment.objects.create(total_price=10)

RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: Payment has no invoice.

>>> Payment.objects.create(total_price=10,invoice=Invoice.objects.first())

TypeError: 'invoice' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Can't figure out why is that so. I want `Invoice` to have an optional argument `payment` and vice versa because `Payment` object is created after recieved payment.

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    identificator = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    order = models.OneToOneField('Job', related_name='invoice', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price_per_word = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=12)
    translator_revenue_in_percent = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    discount_in_percent = models.FloatField(default=0)
    final_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    estimated_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    payment = models.OneToOneField('Payment', related_name='invoice', null=True, blank=True)
    __original_paid = None

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        if not self.__original_paid and self.paid:
            self.__original_paid = True
            if self.order.translator:
                EventHandler.order_has_been_paid(self.order)

        super(Invoice, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Payment(models.Model):
    payment_identifier = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        EventHandler.order_has_been_paid(self.invoice.order)
        super(Payment,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Do you know where is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You override the `save` method of your `Payment` model to access a `self.invoice` which apparently does not exist because there isn't a saved payment yet, talk less an invoice.